# Register new user in ejabberd with REST API

Tags: rest, authentication, token, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I am using ejabberd-18.01 on Windows 10 (localhost). I am trying to connect to ejabberd via [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) using the web method:

POST: localhost:5280/api/specific_api_method

As per the official API documentation (https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/), I am trying to add a roster item using the POST method with the body that follows:

POST: localhost:5280/api/add_rosteritem

`{
    "localuser": "user1",
    "localserver": "mydomain",
    "user": "admin",
    "server": "mydomain",
    "nick": "u1",
    "group": "Friends",
    "subs": "both"
}`

I am getting an error:

`{
    "status": "error",
    "code": 32,
    "message": "AccessRules: Account does not have the right to perform the operation."
}`

I will be grateful if somebody can guide me how to authenticate myself and add a new user or roster item to ejabberd using the web API. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Are you using OAuth to Authenticate? Do you have a token for example?

When I do API requests the look like the following;

curl -ik -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' https://localhost:5280/api/specific_api_method -d '{}'

Answer (score 2):

make these changes in your yml file config file

*change loopback in acl to this:*

```
loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"
      - "::1/128"
      - "::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128"
```

*and use this api_permissions:*

```
api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      - access:
          - allow:
            - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
            - acl: admin
      - oauth:
        - scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        - access:
          - allow:
              - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
              - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      - acl: loopback
    what:
      - "status"
      - "register"
      - "connected_users_number"
```

this issue have been closed at : [Access denied issue on ejabberd](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2208)